# Windows subsystem for Linux : Command Not Found Error

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I have installed **windows subsystem for Linux** to run Ubuntu `16.04` on my windows 10 home platform.
I have extracted all required directories to run `KSQL` on this platform.

Now, when I am trying to run any command after navigating to the bin folder. It's throwing command not found error. I tried to add `PATH` as well but it's not working.

Please suggest.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There's a typo in your command:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/opt/kafka/confleuent-5.4.0/bin
```

Instead of `confluent-5.4.0` you misspelled it `confleuent-5.4.0`.

---

The easiest way to install Confluent CLI, is by making use of the [scripted installation](https://docs.confluent.io/current/cli/installing.html):

> Install the Confluent CLI using this script. This command creates a
>   bin directory in your designated location (`<path-to-directory>/bin`).
>   The location must be in your `PATH` (e.g. `/usr/local/bin`). On Microsoft
>   Windows, an appropriate Linux environment may need to be installed in
>   order to have the curl and sh commands available, such as the Windows
>   Subsystem for Linux

```
curl -L https://cnfl.io/cli | sh -s -- -b /<path-to-directory>/bin
```

Finally, if you run `confluent start` you can get all services up and running, including KSQL (assuming that you have correct configuration files).

Answer (score 0):

You could just use the path

```
cd bin
```

./kafka-topics.sh

Also, all those commands work in CMD / PowerShell as well

If you want to run KSQL, I'd suggest just using Docker